# Proving $\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\cos\frac{\left(2j+1\right)\pi}{2N}=0$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

Let $l\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$. I need to prove the following:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\cos\left(l\frac{\left(2j+1\right)\pi}{2N} \right)=0
\end{equation}
I tried to use Euler formula and then sum the first $N$ terms of the geometric serie I get, but it didn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Compare the $j$ term with the $N-1-j$ term.

Comment: Thanks! @LordSharktheUnknown